# rotate is not working in css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have tried to rotate the + icon `rotate(0deg)` to `rotate(48deg)` but i don't want to rotate the background.

The button act slide animation. Please suggest me how to resolve this in CSS or javascript.

**HTML**

```
<button class="test_rotate"></button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.test_rotate:hover::after, .test_rotate:active::after {
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.test_rotate::after {
    content: attr(data-content);
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #239a98;
    border: solid 8px transparent;
    transition: transform .25s ease,background-color .25s ease;
    -ms-transform: translate(40px, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(40px, 0);
    transform: translate(40px, 0);
    border-top-left-radius: 54px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 54px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    font-size: larger;
}
```

**Demo**: https://codepen.io/burner/pen/MEqpWB

Comment: So you want to rotate everything inside the button but not the button itself? Asking this because I've pasted your code into jsfiddle but what I see hardly makes any sense.

Comment: yes, I want to rotate only icon not all.

Comment: What does `data-content` contains? Can you make a working example?

Comment: @Balázs, added demo page, please suggest me

Comment: @CristianTraìna, "data-content" property fetching the icon value in jquery.

Comment: @jinfy I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Balázs, transition is missing, i add transition property background also rotated I don't want to rotate background.